# Unit testing a verticle deployment

Tags: java, junit, rx-java, vert.x

I have a simple Verticle that reads configuration from a properties file and loads in into vertx config. I have written a unit test to test the deployment of this verticle and possible cause of test failure is non availability of the properties file at the location.

When I run the test, unit test passes irrespective of whether I change the properties file name or path and the handler says the verticle was deployed successfully.

Am I doing something wrong here? Below is my code

```
import io.vertx.config.ConfigRetrieverOptions;
import io.vertx.config.ConfigStoreOptions;
import io.vertx.core.DeploymentOptions;
import io.vertx.core.json.JsonObject;
import io.vertx.rxjava.config.ConfigRetriever;
import io.vertx.rxjava.core.AbstractVerticle;


/**
 * This is the main launcher verticle, the following operations will be executed in start() method of this verticle:
 * 1. Read configurations from application.properties file
 * 2. Deploy all other verticles in the application
 */
public class LauncherVerticle extends AbstractVerticle {


    @Override
    public void start() throws Exception {

        //set up configuration from the properties file
        ConfigStoreOptions fileStore = new ConfigStoreOptions()
                .setType("file")
                .setFormat("properties")
                .setConfig(new JsonObject().put("path", System.getProperty("vertex.config.path"));

        //create config retriever options add properties to filestore
        ConfigRetrieverOptions options = new ConfigRetrieverOptions().addStore(fileStore);
        ConfigRetriever configRetriever = ConfigRetriever.create(vertx, options);

        DeploymentOptions deploymentOptions = new DeploymentOptions();

        //Deploy verticles after the config has been loaded
        //The configurations are loaded into JsonConfig object
        //This JsonConfig object can be accessed in other verticles using the config() method.
        configRetriever.rxGetConfig().subscribe(s -> {

            //pass on the JsonConfig object to other verticles through deployment options
            deploymentOptions.setConfig(s);
            vertx.deployVerticle(AnotherVerticle.class.getName(), deploymentOptions);

        }, e -> {
            log.error("Failed to start application : " + e.getMessage(), e);
            try {
                stop();
            } catch (Exception e1) {
                log.error("Unable to stop vertx, terminate the process manually : "+e1.getMessage(), e1);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

**This is my unit test**

```
import io.vertx.ext.unit.TestContext;
import io.vertx.ext.unit.junit.VertxUnitRunner;
import io.vertx.rxjava.core.Vertx;
import org.junit.Assert;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import rx.Single;


@RunWith(VertxUnitRunner.class)
public class LoadConfigurationTest {


    /**
     * Config should be loaded successfully
     *
     * @param context
     */
    @Test
    public void loadConfigTest(TestContext context) {
        /*
         * Set the system property "vertx.config.path" with value "application.properties"
         * This system property will be used in the Launcher verticle to read the config file
         */
        System.setProperty("vertx.config.path", "/opt/vertx/config/application.properties");

        //create vertx instance
        Vertx vertx = Vertx.vertx();

        Single<String> single = vertx.rxDeployVerticle(LauncherVerticle.class.getName());
        single.subscribe(s -> {
            vertx.rxUndeploy(s);
        }, e -> {
            Assert.fail(e.getMessage());
        });

    }

    /**
     * Test for negative use case - file not available in the specified location
     *
     * @param context
     */
    @Test
    public void loadConfigFailTest(TestContext context) {

         //set path = non existing path
        System.setProperty("vertx.config.path", "/non/existing/path/application.properties");

        //create vertx instance
        Vertx vertx = Vertx.vertx();

        Single single = vertx.rxDeployVerticle(LauncherVerticle.class.getName());

        single.subscribe(s -> {
            //not executing this statement
            Assert.fail("Was expecting error but Verticle deployed successfully");
        }, e -> {
            //not executing this statement either
            System.out.println("pass");
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you try the below code inside your `LauncherVerticle` the changes only include using `AbstractVerticles` `start` with `Future` which is a neat way for handling the config loading and everything around the same during your starup.

```
public class LauncherVerticle extends AbstractVerticle {
@Override
public void start(Future<Void> startFuture) throws Exception {
        ConfigStoreOptions fileStore = new ConfigStoreOptions()
                .setType("file")
                .setFormat("properties")
                .setConfig(new JsonObject().put("path", System.getProperty("vertex.config.path")));

        ConfigRetrieverOptions options = new ConfigRetrieverOptions().addStore(fileStore);
        ConfigRetriever configRetriever = ConfigRetriever.create(vertx, options);

        DeploymentOptions deploymentOptions = new DeploymentOptions();
        configRetriever.rxGetConfig().subscribe(s -> {
                    deploymentOptions.setConfig(s);
                    vertx.deployVerticle(AnotherVerticle.class.getName(),
                            deploymentOptions,
                            result -> startFuture.complete()
                    );
                },
                startFuture::fail
        );
    }
}
```

`startFuture` there, would help you to control the state of your verticle loading.

Also remember that @Constantine way for handing the test is best way, use of `Async` to prevent your tests passing without actually asserting anything.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like there is nothing wrong with your verticle. However, there is something in tests - the asynchronous nature of verticle deployment is not taken into account. These test methods finish immediately instead of waiting for verticle deployment, and JUnit test that does not result in `AssertionError` is a **passed test**. You have to signal completion explicitly using `Async`.

Please see an example for your negative scenario below:

```
import io.vertx.ext.unit.Async;
import io.vertx.ext.unit.TestContext;
import io.vertx.ext.unit.junit.RunTestOnContext;
import io.vertx.ext.unit.junit.VertxUnitRunner;
import io.vertx.rxjava.core.Vertx;
import org.junit.Rule;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;

@RunWith(VertxUnitRunner.class)
public class LoadConfigurationTest {

    @Rule
    public RunTestOnContext runTestOnContextRule = new RunTestOnContext();

    @Test
    public void testConfigLoading_shouldFail_whenConfigDoesNotExist(TestContext context) {
        // create an Async instance that controls the completion of the test
        Async async = context.async();

        // set non existing path
        System.setProperty("vertx.config.path", "/non/existing/path/application.properties");

        // take vertx instance and wrap it with rx-ified version
        Vertx vertx = Vertx.newInstance(runTestOnContextRule.vertx());

        vertx.rxDeployVerticle(LauncherVerticle.class.getName()).subscribe(s -> {
            context.fail("Was expecting error but Verticle deployed successfully"); // failure
        }, e -> {
            async.complete(); // success
        });
    }
}
```

Also please note that you can take a `Vertx` instance from `RunTestOnContext` rule (as in the snippet above).

Comment: Thanks Constantine, but using vertx instance from `RunTestOnContext` will give not give rxified version of vertx which is what I need.

Comment: Glad that helped. The `Vertx` instance from `RunTestOnContext` is not rxified indeed. That's why I wrap it with `io.vertx.rxjava.core.Vertx.newInstance(runTestOnContextRule.vertx())`. However, you could simply use non-rxified version in tests, since rxified one is not a different implementation, but just a wrapper over functionality of `io.vertx.core.Vertx`.

Comment: I add the link to the response to the same question on the vertx mailing: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/vertx/ccCLBWVAcX0